# Kannel configuration for CSMS on AT

Tags: kannel

I am working on a web app that is configured to send smses to mobile clients. My main problem is with the sms settings on the kannel gateway(new to framwork!). When I run the bearerbox, I get the following stack..

```
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [0] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: start called
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: device opened. Telnet mode = 0
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: device opened
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: speed set to 9600
2013-01-10 16:17:34 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> ^M
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT^M
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- AT
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: Closing device
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: speed is 9600
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: opening device
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: device opened. Telnet mode = 0
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: device opened
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: Logging in
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: init device
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: speed set to 9600
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> ATZ^M
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- ATZ
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT^M
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- AT
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:36 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT&F^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- AT&F
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> ATE0^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- ATE0
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> ATQ0^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT+CPIN?^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- +CPIN: READY
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT+CMGF=0^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT+CSMS=?^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- +CSMS: (0,1,128)
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- OK
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: Phase 2+ is supported
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: --> AT+CSMS=1^M
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- +CSMS: 1,1,1
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] DEBUG: AT2[Huawei]: <-- ERROR
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] ERROR: AT2[Huawei]: Generic error: ERROR
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] ERROR: AT2[Huawei]: Initialization of device failed.
2013-01-10 16:17:37 [4875] [6] INFO: AT2[Huawei]: Closing device
```

I've checked around for similar problems but can't seem to get a clear solution as none of them works so far.
Any help is greatly appreciated...